# Liferay 6 on Glassfish 3.1 - issue using liferay-ui tags in portlet jsp files

Tags: glassfish-3, cluster-computing, noclassdeffounderror, liferay-6

We are seeing this issue on our current Glassfish 3.1 cluster setup. Below are details of issue
- We are running Glassfish version 3.1

- We are running liferay 6.0.6
- The liferay war is deployed on the Glassfish cluster and working fine on both the nodes.
- The same liferay war works fine one Tomcat server as well.
- When we deploy our custom portlets on Glassfish cluster it starts working immediately after deployment. (before doing a restart of glassfish cluster)
- Once we do a restart of the cluster nodes the same portlet application stops working and Complains and give attached error.
- My research till now shows that the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/util/PropsValues is part of portal-impl.jar file which is part of liferay portal and should be made available to our portlet. Somehow after the restart the jar files are loaded in a different manner and the same jar file is not available to portlet.
- We have also tried the Glassfish 3.1 Bundled liferay 6.1 setup and see the same issue on it as well.
- As suggested by liferay forums we have placed the portal-service.jar and portlet.jar in [glassfish home]/lib directory.
- when we do a lsof -p pid on the glassfish node instance process it shows the required jar file is open by this process. Not sure why is this not available to our application.

I would appreciate any help or pointers to resolve/investigate this issue.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/util/PropsValues
    at org.apache.jsp.html.taglib.ui.search_005fiterator.page_jsp._jspService(page_jsp.java from :500)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:323)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag._doInclude(IncludeTag.java:418)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:92)
```

This is a related thread on liferay forum by me but I have not really got any response on it from anyone. [[Same issue posted on liferay Forum]](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11547555)

i have also tried placing portal-impl.jar in my portlet/WEB-INF/lib dir (which is not recommended way) and I failed since it requires me to bring all other dependent jars in it too.

I am now running out of options and thinking about implementing the pagination feature using some other third party library instead of using liferay tags.

Here is the specific tag which is giving us error

```
        <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
```

List of jars in my portlet WEB-INF/lib folder

```
    SiebelClientWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
    spring-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar
    spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar    
    spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    axiom-api-1.2.11.jar
    spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    axiom-impl-1.2.11.jar
    spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    axis2-1.5.4.jar
    spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    axis2-kernel-1.5.4.jar
    spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    axis2-transport-http-1.5.4.jar
    spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    axis2-transport-local-1.5.4.jar
    spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar    
    spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    commons-codec-1.4.jar
    spring-webmvc-portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
    util-bridges.jar
    commons-logging.jar
    util-java.jar
    flexjson-2.1.jar    
    util-taglib.jar
    httpcore-4.0.jar    
    woden-api-1.0M9.jar
    httpcore-nio-4.0-beta1.jar
    woden-impl-commons-1.0M9.jar
    log4j.jar
    woden-impl-dom-1.0M9.jar
    neethi-2.0.2.jar    
    wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
    spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    wss4j-1.6.2.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed

> /html/taglib/ui/search_paginator/page.jsp
>      /html/taglib/ui/search_iterator/page.jsp
>      /html/taglib/ui/page_iterator/start.jsp

and removed the calls to PropsValues and replaced them with calls to the `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil` and `PropsKeys` instead and that go the rid of the error for me.

I made an improvement request
http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-30660

Answer (score 0):

> com/liferay/portal/util/PropsValues is part of portal-impl.jar file which is part of liferay portal and should be made available to our portlet.

That is not true, `portal-impl.jar` is not available to your portlets and it is not meant to. You MUST NOT put it in your `WEB-INF/lib`. That jar is only available, and should be that way, to Liferay (liferay application).

Can you show contents (list of jars) of your (deployed) portlets WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, here is the list of jars I have in my WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the list. Can you update your question with it?

Comment: Sorry had issue with edits, it took a while for me to update that. its up thr now.

Comment: BTW, the search-iterator tag uses a class from portal-impl.jar and thats what makes me think it needs to be made available.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question? you mean the CLASSPATH env variable value?

Comment: I am not setting the env classpath explicitly. Glassfish using the default classpath it uses.